# How do I write a macro that will repeat a command?

Tags: macros, common-lisp

I'm trying to write a macro that will let me streamline the definition of multiple top-level variables in one single expression.

The idea was to make it work similar to how `let` works:

```
(defparameters ((*foo* 42)
                (*bar* 31)
                (*baz* 99)))
```

I tried using the following, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

```
(defmacro defparameters (exprs)
  (dolist (expr exprs)
    (let ((name (car  expr))
          (exp  (cadr expr)))
      `(defparameter ,name ,exp))))
```

I've tried using `macroexpand` but it doesn't seem to expand at all.

What am I doing wrong? and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return value of a `dolist` is given by its optional third argument, so your macro returns the default of `nil`.

Macros only return one form, so when you have multiple things, such as your series of `defparameters`, you need to wrap them all in some form and return that. `progn` will be suitable here. For Example:

```
(defmacro defparameters (exprs)
  `(progn ,@(loop for (name exp) in exprs
                  collect `(defparameter ,name ,exp))))
```